# When I'm buying a videocard, which components are from ATI\nVidia?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, components

It's very common to buy a video card from a manufacturer that is not the manufacturer of the GPU.

So I always ask myself: Am I buying a product completely built by the manufacturer, with the GPU as the only exception? Or is there something else like the PCB or the VRAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nvidia and Amd produce the core gpu. Nvidia also makes "reference cards" which are often entirely made by Nvidia with the manufacturers branding slapped onto it. Companies such as EVGA make their own pcb's to come up with enthusiast products such as gtx 780 KING PIN edition that has a much larger pcb and is capable of liquid nitrogen cooled overclocking.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the only component from the ATI/NVidia is the actual GPU chipset. PCB, RAM, fans, etc. are all done by the adapter manufacturer.

Comment: Yes even if it is a "reference" card the only part made by ATI (Now known and owned as AMD) and nVidia is the GPU itself.

Comment: So GPU manufacturers have _"only"_ to design and produce gpus and documentation?

Comment: They tend to build their own prototypes and some end use cards as well, so not quite. It's always an involved multi-corporation project.

Comment: @mordack550 Don't forget the software. That's a huge fraction of the work.